# Transform pandas Series with variable length comma separated values to Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas-Series 'A' containing comma separated values like this :

```
index    A

1        null
2        5,6
3        3
4        null
5        5,18,22
...      ...
```

I need a dataframe like this :

```
index    A_5    A_6    A_18    A_20

1        0      0      0       ...
2        1      1      0       ...
3        0      0      0       ...
4        0      0      0       ...
5        1      0      1       ...
...      ...    ...    ...     ...
```

Values that don't occur at least MIN_OBS times should be ignored and not get an own column, because there are so many distinct values that the df would become too big if this threshold isn't applied.

I designed the solution below. It works, but is way too slow (due to iterating over rows I suppose). Could anyone suggest a faster approach ?

```
temp_dict = defaultdict(int)
for k, v in A.iteritems():
    temp_list = v.split(',')
    for item in temp_list:
        temp_dict[item] += 1

cols_to_make = []
for k, v in temp_dict.iteritems():
    if v > MIN_OBS:
        cols_to_make.append('A_' + k)

result_df = pd.DataFrame(0, index = the_series.index, columns = cols_to_make)
for k, v in A.iteritems():
    temp_list = v.split(',')
    for item in temp_list:
    if ('A_' + item) in cols_to_make:
        temp_df['A_' + item][k] = 1
```

Comment: How are you reading in this series into Pandas to begin with? My initial thought is to use the pandas read_csv function, which will automatically get rid of the `null` rows and will add `null` values to rows that have less columns than they need.

Comment: read_csv would just put values in columns following the order they're in, which wouldn't achieve what I'm looking for (columns based on the actual values)

Comment: Right, but I guess if you used `read_csv` you could eliminate your first `for` loop. How long is your data? Also, what is `defaultdict`? I'm trying to run your code.

Comment: I have around 200,000 rows. There are about 40,000 different possible values. Just add this on top : from collections import defaultdict

Comment: Do you know ahead of time how many maximum column are in your data? For example, in your example, row 5 has 4 columns - is this the max, or could there be more columns?

Comment: Could be any amount...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since memory is an issue, we have to be careful not to build large intermediate
data structures if possible.

Let's start with the OP's posted code that works:

```
def orig(A, MIN_OBS):
    temp_dict = collections.defaultdict(int)
    for k, v in A.iteritems():
        temp_list = v.split(',')
        for item in temp_list:
            temp_dict[item] += 1
    cols_to_make = []
    for k, v in temp_dict.iteritems():
        if v > MIN_OBS:
            cols_to_make.append('A_' + k)

    result_df = pd.DataFrame(0, index=A.index, columns=cols_to_make)
    for k, v in A.iteritems():
        temp_list = v.split(',')
        for item in temp_list:
            if ('A_' + item) in cols_to_make:
                result_df['A_' + item][k] = 1
    return result_df
```

and extract the first loop into its own function:

```
def count(A, MIN_OBS):
    temp_dict = collections.Counter()
    for k, v in A.iteritems():
        temp_list = v.split(',')
        for item in temp_list:
            temp_dict[item] += 1
    temp_dict = {k:v for k, v in temp_dict.items() if v > MIN_OBS}
    return temp_dict
```

From experimentation in an interactive session, we can see this is not the bottleneck; even for "large" DataFrames, `count(A, MIN_OBS)` completes fairly quickly.

The slowness of `orig` occurs in the the double `for-loop` at the end of `orig`
which increments modifies cells in the DataFrame one value at a time
(e.g. `result_df['A_' + item][k] = 1`.)

We could replace that double-for loop with a single for-loop over the columns of the DataFrame, using the vectorized string method, `A.str.contains` to search for values in the strings. Since we never split the original strings into Python lists of strings (or Pandas DataFrames holding the string fragments), we save some memory.
Since `orig` and `alt` use similar data structures, their memory footprint is about the same.

```
def alt(A, MIN_OBS):
    temp_dict = count(A, MIN_OBS)
    df = pd.DataFrame(0, index=A.index, columns=temp_dict)
    for col in df:
        df[col] = A.str.contains(r'^{v}|,{v},|,{v}$'.format(v=col)).astype(int)
    df.columns = ['A_{}'.format(col) for col in df]
    return df
```

---

Here is an example, on a 200K row DataFrame with 40K different possible values:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import collections

np.random.seed(2016)
ncols = 5
nrows = 200000
nvals = 40000
MIN_OBS = 200

# nrows = 20
# nvals = 4
# MIN_OBS = 2

idx = np.random.randint(ncols, size=nrows).cumsum()
data = np.random.choice(np.arange(nvals), size=idx[-1])
data = np.array_split(data, idx[:-1])
data = map(','.join, [map(str, arr) for arr in data])
A = pd.Series(data)
A.loc[A == ''] = 'null'

def orig(A, MIN_OBS):
    temp_dict = collections.defaultdict(int)
    for k, v in A.iteritems():
        temp_list = v.split(',')
        for item in temp_list:
            temp_dict[item] += 1
    cols_to_make = []
    for k, v in temp_dict.iteritems():
        if v > MIN_OBS:
            cols_to_make.append('A_' + k)

    result_df = pd.DataFrame(0, index=A.index, columns=cols_to_make)
    for k, v in A.iteritems():
        temp_list = v.split(',')
        for item in temp_list:
            if ('A_' + item) in cols_to_make:
                result_df['A_' + item][k] = 1
    return result_df

def count(A, MIN_OBS):
    temp_dict = collections.Counter()
    for k, v in A.iteritems():
        temp_list = v.split(',')
        for item in temp_list:
            temp_dict[item] += 1
    temp_dict = {k:v for k, v in temp_dict.items() if v > MIN_OBS}
    return temp_dict

def alt(A, MIN_OBS):
    temp_dict = count(A, MIN_OBS)
    df = pd.DataFrame(0, index=A.index, columns=temp_dict)
    for col in df:
        df[col] = A.str.contains(r'^{v}|,{v},|,{v}$'.format(v=col)).astype(int)
    df.columns = ['A_{}'.format(col) for col in df]
    return df
```

---

Here is a benchmark:

```
In [48]: %timeit expected = orig(A, MIN_OBS)
1 loops, best of 3: 3.03 s per loop

In [49]: %timeit expected = alt(A, MIN_OBS)
1 loops, best of 3: 483 ms per loop
```

Note that the majority of the time required for `alt` to complete is spent in `count`:

```
In [60]: %timeit count(A, MIN_OBS)
1 loops, best of 3: 304 ms per loop
```

Comment: Executing s.str.split(',').apply(pd.Series).stack() kills the kernel on my computer (Intel i5-CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4  with 8GB RAM)

Comment: Okay, in that case we can try to conserve memory by avoiding the creation of intermediate DataFrames (in particular, by not creating lists of string fragments). I've updated the post above to show what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) for creating indicator variables, then convert columns to numbers by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) and last filter columns by variable `TRESH` and [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html):

```
print df
             A
index         
1         null
2          5,6
3            3
4         null
5      5,18,22

df = df.A.str.get_dummies(sep=",")
print df
       18  22  3  5  6  null
index                       
1       0   0  0  0  0     1
2       0   0  0  1  1     0
3       0   0  1  0  0     0
4       0   0  0  0  0     1
5       1   1  0  1  0     0

df.columns = pd.to_numeric(df.columns, errors='coerce')
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)

TRESH = 5
cols = [col for col in df.columns if col > TRESH]
print cols
[6.0, 18.0, 22.0]
```

```
df = df.ix[:, cols]
print df
       6   18  22
index            
1       0   0   0
2       1   0   0
3       0   0   0
4       0   0   0
5       0   1   1

df.columns = ["A_" + str(int(col)) for col in df.columns]
print df
       A_6  A_18  A_22
index                 
1        0     0     0
2        1     0     0
3        0     0     0
4        0     0     0
5        0     1     1
```

EDIT:

I try modified perfect original [`unutbu answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35088748/1) and change creating `Series`, removing `Series` with `null` values in `index` and add parameter `prefix` to [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['null', '5,6', '3', 'null', '5,18,22', '3,4'])
print s

#result = s.str.split(',').apply(pd.Series).stack()
#replacing to:
result = pd.DataFrame([ x.split(',') for x in s ]).stack()
count = pd.value_counts(result)

min_obs = 2

#add removing Series, which contains null
count = count[(count >= min_obs) & ~(count.index.isin(['null'])) ]

result = result.loc[result.isin(count.index)]
#add prefix to function get_dummies
result = pd.get_dummies(result, prefix="A")

result.index = result.index.droplevel(1)
result = result.reindex(s.index)

print(result)
   A_3  A_5
0  NaN  NaN
1    0    1
2    1    0
3  NaN  NaN
4    0    1
5    1    0
```

Timings:

```
In [143]: %timeit pd.DataFrame([ x.split(',') for x in s ]).stack()
1000 loops, best of 3: 866 µs per loop

In [144]: %timeit s.str.split(',').apply(pd.Series).stack()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.46 ms per loop
```

Comment: Get_dummies is the way to go indeed. But the threshold serves to keep those columns that have at least that amount of ones in them. The current code doesn't do that.

Comment: Unfortunately, trying to execute   df = df.A.str.get_dummies(sep=",")   causes a MemoryError

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work or could it be modified to fit your need?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['null', '5,6', '3', 'null', '5,18,22']}, columns=['A'])

         A
0     null
1      5,6
2        3
3     null
4  5,18,22
```

Then use `get_dummies()`

```
pd.get_dummies(df['A'].str.split(',').apply(pd.Series), prefix=df.columns[0])
```

Result:

```
       A_3  A_5  A_null  A_18  A_6  A_22
index                                   
1        0    0       1     0    0     0
2        0    1       0     0    1     0
3        1    0       0     0    0     0
4        0    0       1     0    0     0
5        0    1       0     1    0     1
```